# Unit testing with EasyMock and Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, easymock

In my project i have UtilClass for example A(all method static, private constructor). I need to test one of this static method a(13 parameters). This class have one dependencies(another class B). Class B - static field in class A. In code smth like that:

```
public class A{
    private static B b = AppContext.getBean(B.class);

    public static C a("14 parameters") throw MyException{
        try{
        b.call("13 parameters");
        }catch(MyExceptionSecond e){
            MyException newException = new MyException(msg,e);
            if(e.getCode() == smth){
                //do smth
            }
            throw privateMethodClassA(newException);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to test how working privateMethodClassA, for that i mocked class B in config-test.xml:

```
<bean class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock" primary="true" id="classB">
    <constructor-arg value="com.my.package.B"/>
</bean>
```

That is my test and setUp method:

```
public class MyTest {
   private B b;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    b = AppContext.getBean(B.class);
    expect(b.call("13 paramaters"))
        .andThrow(
            new MyExceptionSecond("some error code", "testMessage", new Object()))
        .anyTimes();
    replay(b);
}

@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void testExceptionMethod() throws Exception {
    A.a("13 parametrs");
}
}
```

If I evaluating in debug b.call("13 parameters") everything all right(in context test), but in the same debug going into context call class A and evaluate b.call("13 parameters
") with the same parameters mocked object return null, instead of MyExceptionSecond as in the first case. The problem is - i can't get the MyException error all my attempts led to : 
`java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: com.my.package.MyException`
What do you think about this issue?

P.S My guess is that this is a problem in the attachment of expect() to the context of the test and not to the moсk itself.

P.P.S java8, EasyMock 4.2, spring 4.2.8, AppContext == org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.

Comment: `B.call(String... args);` Does it even compile? Please show us code without such mistakes, and also signature of `B.call`

Comment: B - rest client from another app. I fixed all mistakes in my pseudo code

Comment: The risk of posting pseudocode is that people will find bugs in your pseudocode, not in your real code. Can you post a minimal, but real example where you can reproduce the problem? `public static C a("14 parameters") throw MyException` does not compile. Is "14 parameters" a placeholder? In a different place you have "13 parameters". Is it intended?

Comment: Yes, "13 parameters" it's placeholder (in real life 1int , 1boolean, null, 10 strings). I think it's doesn't matter

Comment: It should work. Can you post a full working use-case that we can try?